# Derivate of the Limit of sequence function in $\mathcal{C}'([0,1]$

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

> Let $\{x_n\}_n \subset \mathcal{C}^1([0,1])$ such that $||x_n-x||_{\infty} \rightarrow 0$ and $||x_{n}^{'}-y||_{\infty} \rightarrow 0$ show that $y \in \mathcal{C}([0,1])$ and $x'=y$

I proved that $y \in \mathcal{C}([0,1])$ because by the hyp. $||x_{n}^{'}-y||_{\infty} \rightarrow 0$  deduce that $y$ is the limit of continous functions because every $x_n \in \mathcal{C}^1([0,1])$ then $x_n' \in \mathcal{C}^1([0,1])$, $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$, but i have problems to prove the equality $x'=y$ i think to use the mean value theorem of maybe fundamental calculus theorem but i dont sure.
Every suggestion or hint i will very grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WLOG, we assume that $x_n(0) = 0$ for all $n$ and $x(0) = 0$. Then for any $t \in [0,T]$, we have the estimate
\begin{align}
   \big|\int_0^t y(s) ds - x(t)\big|
   ~ \leq \int_{0}^t |y(s) - x^\prime_n(s)| ds 
   ~ +    \big|\int_0^t x^\prime_n(s) ds - x_n(t)\big|
   ~ + |x_n(t) - x(t)|
\end{align}
Then we can see the conclusion holds.

Comment: i think to i catch the idea but i dont not sure how i work with the factor $$|\int_{0}^t x_n'(s)ds-x_n(t)|$$

Comment: it  just equals to 0.

Comment: oh i cant see why :$ please you can explain me

Comment: it is the newton-leibniz formula.

Comment: ohhh i see!! thanks :)